# Could not connect Heroku CLI with heroku postgres for java application

Tags: java, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I have added Postgres addon in heroku. I have heroku cli. But when I try to execute heroku pg:psql from cli I get an error couldnot resolve host to address.
Provided I didnot do anything for ssl. I have postgres database installed in my machine and path variable is also set.
I went through some solutions but couldnot find something very good solution related to my issue.
Can anyone help me?

Also I want to add table in heroku postgres.

Comment: Are you running behind a proxy?

Comment: yes I am behind proxy. Do you know what problem I am facing?